# cURL to my own server crashes apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ubuntu-14.04, curl

I'm running a apache web sever on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I found myself in a situation where I from a php script on one server requested data from another php script on a second server. Both servers are under my control.

Entering the `url` for the script I was requesting worked fine. But when requesting it by using `cURL` the server crashed. Not the server who was requesting data, but the server being contacted with curl.

Is there a scenario where a cURL request being processed differently from a regular request from a browser? I can't seem to find anything useful in my log files either. I guess i could do a workaround but it's not good that anyone contacting my server using curl crashes it?

I've pasted my curl script below.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashed"?

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly is happening, since the error logs dosen't say much. But it's a vps that stops responding to http requests and ssh.

Comment: Seeing something similar on nginx because of curl, epic slowness and freezes on my site. Any updates?